# Can't install the g Scatter add-on in preferences

Tags: add-on

I am having trouble with installing the gscatter addon, and I would greatly appreciate some help.
I use blender 3.3.0. on a macbook. After downloading the g scatter files, a folder appears and when i try to install the add on in preferences, there's a lot of folders and python scripts in the g scatter folder and i can't figure out what exactly to download. I have searched for tutorials on youtube but in all of them, a zip file named ' gscatter 0.6.0 ' or something appears but I can't navigate such a file in the downloaded folder. Even when i try to install some of the python files like installer etc, it doesn't happen. I am sure I'm doing something wrong but I absolutely can't seem to figure it out.
I am a beginner and any help would be extremely helpful.
Regards

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://graswald.notion.site/Download-Installation-Gscatter-and-Assets-dbe897a471fb47ce9661c48fdc23fec1

Comment: hey I've already tried this but it still isn't showing

Comment: Have you unpacked the zip file?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a Mac issue, the files were getting unzipped automatically. If you're facing a similar problem,

1. open safari
2. go to settings>general and untick ' open "safe" files after downloading '.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, Safari automatically unpacks zip files or something, which makes installing a bit annoying.

But even with the zip file unpacked, you can still move that folder into Blender's scripts folder.

It is located inside the "user folder", you can see the user path location on [this page depending on your system](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#platform-dependent-paths).

Alternatively, you can move it to a custom script folder of your choosing. Then, add that custom script folder to your [custom script folders settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/file_paths.html#script-directories) in Edit > Preferences > File Paths:

[image]